# while converting cgm to cgm internally the colormode indexed is not working but the colormode direct is working fine. How to change it internally

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert the CGM to CGM file internally. If i convert the CGM to CTX and changed the colrmode attribute to direct from indexed. The conversion is done correctly. If it is in indexed the cgm is coming as blank file. How to change the attribute's value through my C++ code

I need a cgm to cgm conversion through C++ code. I tried by converting the cgm to ctx and changed the value directly. It is converted correctly. Now I have to change the value through the C++ code

Comment: Why did you repeat yourself? I assume Stack Overflow rejected the question before with something like "too few contents" or so. Didn't it recommend it to add a [mcve]? Please, [edit] and improve your question. And, btw. it couldn't hurt to take the [tour] and read [ask] (what you didn't yet).